# Jquery selector based on class and parent name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to verify if the clicked cell on a devexpress grid is valid according to the following rules:

- Click on a cell that has classes: `.dxgv.dx-ar` (This part is working)
- If that element contains some element of the class `gridValue` AND this (child) element has a father with name: 'allowsEdit' (THIS CODE IS NOT WORKIING)

I was trying to avoid using the ".parent()..." adicional line, but combine multiple JQuery selector rules, but till now I was not able.

Any ideas?

JS

```
$('#' + gridIdName).unbind('click').on('click', '.dxgv.dx-ar', function (e) {        
    if ($(this).find('.gridValue:parent[name="allowsEdit"]').length !== 0) {
        console.log('FOUND');
        return
    }
    console.log('NOT FOUND');
});
```

HTML

```
/******** VALID *************/
<td id="devGrid1_tccell2_13" class="dxgv dx-ar">
    <div style="width: 100%;" name="allowsEdit" class="contextMenuElement TargetIdstate VarietyId76 Year2018 CountryId2 PlanId11437">
        <div style="width:100%;" id="state_76_2_2018" class="gridValue gridValueMin1 gridValueMax11">
            2000
        </div>   
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</td>
/******** NOT VALID *************/
<td id="devGrid1_tccell3_7" class="dxgv dx-ar" style="background-color:#E4AA8A;">
    <div style="width: 100%;" name="" class="contextMenuElement TargetIdactual VarietyId82 Year2018 CountryId1 PlanId12732">
        <div style="width:37px;" id="actual_82_1_2018" class="gridValue">
            40000
        </div>   
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: why not just use `$(this).find('div[name="allowsEdit"]')` ?

Comment: @ For WHOM down voted the question, please add some comments about it and explain what is the problem....

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Because the code I am showing is the simplified version, and I have SEVERAL elements inside the possible one that allows edit, and I speficically need to know if the one with .gridvalue is there.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't match your description of what you want. You said that the `name="allowsEdit"` element is the "father" of the `.dxgv.dx-ar` element, but it isn't, it's a *child* of it. Is the description wrong, or is the HTML wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple css selector for this

```
[name="allowsEdit"] > .gridValue
```

this selects the .gridValue element. if you directly want the allowsEditElement you can use:

```
[name="allowsEdit"]:has(.gridValue)
```

find `.gridValue` class elements where direct parent have class: `.allowEdit`

```
$(this).find('[name="allowsEdit"]:has(.gridValue)').length
```

For more information you can read [Mozzila's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) about this

Comment: `allowsedit` is a **name**, not a class, and the OP said he/she wants to select the `.dxgv.dx-ar` element, not the `.gridValue` element (but only when it *has* a `.gridValue` element).

Answer (score 1):

> - Click on a cell that has classes: .dxgv.dx-ar
> - If that element contains some element of the class gridValue AND this element has a father with name: 'allowsEdit'

Your HTML doesn't match that description, but the above is a straightforward combination of:

- An [attribute value selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation)
- A [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators)
- A pair of [class selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#class-html)
- A [`:has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) (which is a jQuery addition)

So all in one it would be: `[name=allowsEdit] .dxgv.dx-ar:has(.gridValue)`

E.g.:

```
$('#' + gridIdName).unbind('click').on('click', '[name=allowsEdit] .dxgv.dx-ar:has(.gridValue)', function (e) {
```

That's if you don't want the clicks at all unless it's a match.

But if you want the click regardless and then just want to check the other things afterward:

```
$('#' + gridIdName).unbind('click').on('click', '.dxgv.dx-ar', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.closest("[name=allowEdit]").length && $this.find(".gridValue").length) {
        // Match
    } else {
        // No match
    }
```

Comment: It seems based on his html example allowsEdit is inside .dxgv element im not sure this would work.

Comment: @JoelHarkes: Yeah, the description of what he/she wants doesn't match the HTML.